# Signing JWT in Postman with RS384 Private Key

Tags: javascript, oauth, postman

I am trying to mock up a request for an an access token which uses a signed JWT in the request. The receiver requires a JWT signed using RS384 which it doesn't look like Crypto-JS included in Postman supports. I've tried a couple other libraries and am also having an issue.

Can anyone offer advice on a library or method in Postman to use to sign a JWT using RS384. The code I would use for SHA-256 is below, but there is no equivalent to RS384 according to the documentation (although I did find a comparison chart that says Crypto-JS can do RS384, I can't find any information in their docs about it).

```
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token, jwtSecret)
signature = base64url(signature)
var signedToken = `${token}.${signature}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this message and is looking for a solution I was able to get the following library to work:

https://joolfe.github.io/postman-util-lib/